# Getting undefined symbols for arm64 (using curlcpp)

Tags: c++, macos, curl, clion

I am currently trying to use the [curlcpp](https://github.com/JosephP91/curlcpp) library; however, when I try to make an API call to OpenWeatherMaps I receive a "undefined symbols for architecture arm64" error below:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "__ZN4curl14curl_exceptionC2ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_", referenced from:
      __ZN4curl19curl_easy_exceptionC1ERK8CURLcodeRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE in main.cpp.o
  "_curl_easy_setopt", referenced from:
      __ZN4curl9curl_easy3addIL10CURLoption10002EEEvNS_6detail8option_tIXT_EE4typeE in main.cpp.o
  "_curl_easy_strerror", referenced from:
      __ZN4curl19curl_easy_exceptionC1ERK8CURLcodeRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I am currently using CLion, on M1 MacOS.  My CMak files looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(TerminalWeather)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/curlcpp/2.1/include/curlcpp)
LINK_LIBRARIES(/opt/homebrew/lib/libcurlcpp.dylib)


add_executable(TerminalWeather src/main.cpp)
```

This is what my main C++ file looks like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <curlcpp/curl_easy.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    using curl::curl_easy, curl::curl_easy_exception;

    /* object handler to make the URL requests */
    curl_easy handler;
    handler.add<CURLOPT_URL>("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={myCity}&units=metric&appid={myAPIKey}");

    try {
        handler.perform();
    } catch(curl_easy_exception& ce) {
        cout << ce.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Could this error be because I am not linking the library properly? I am new to C++ and am not sure how to resolve the issue after looking everywhere.

Thank you all for the help

Comment: It is more like `curlcpp` was installed only for `x64` architecture not for `arm64`. please check properties of library installed by homebrew. You may first read this  https://earthly.dev/blog/homebrew-on-m1/ in hope you will find a solution there.

Comment: thank you for the response, I'll check out the link now